# (Windows 10) Handle incoming phone call in uwp application

Tags: uwp, phone-call, background-task

I need to do some task when the phone has the incoming phone call, but currently, I can not.

I have read sample about background task to be triggered when an unrecognized incoming call arrives at this link [CallerID](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CallerID), and I have tried it, but my background task has not received anything.

Here is register background task code:

```
private async void RegisterTask()
    {
        string phoneObsName = "phoneObsName";
        var access = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
        if (access != BackgroundAccessStatus.Denied &&
            access != BackgroundAccessStatus.Unspecified)
        {
            // Create a new background task builder.
            BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

            // Create a new Phone Trigger.
            PhoneTrigger trigger = new PhoneTrigger(PhoneTriggerType.CallOriginDataRequest, false);

            // Associate the phone trigger with the background task builder.
            taskBuilder.SetTrigger(trigger);

            // Specify the background task to run when the trigger fires.
            taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(BackgroundStuff.PhoneCallBackgroundTask).ToString(); ;

            // Name the background task.
            taskBuilder.Name = phoneObsName;

            // Register the background task.
            BackgroundTaskRegistration taskRegistration = taskBuilder.Register();

            //UpdateBackgroundTaskUIState(true);
            //rootPage.NotifyUser("Registered Caller ID background task", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            //rootPage.NotifyUser("Background agent access denied", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

Please help me to fix my issue.

Comment: Where and when are you calling the RegisterTask method? Also, did you added the background task to the project manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have background task with support task type is phone call at project manifest. I call RegisterTask at App.xaml.cs at the end of OnLaunched().